# Duda con login en Django 2.2

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Estoy integrando un `login` en mi applicacion web, exactamente en la app `registration`, que cree, mi duda surge al momento de mostrar el `login`, en `templates/registration/login.html`.

La forma en que le añado estilos y lo muestro es con HTML en crudo por así decirlo, de la siguiente manera:

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Iniciar sesión{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <style>.errorlist{color:red;}</style>
  <main role="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-md-9 mx-auto mb-5">
          <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <h3 class="mb-4">Iniciar sesión</h3>
            {% if form.non_field_errors %}
              <p style="color:red">Usuario o contraseña incorrectos, prueba de nuevo.</p>
            {% endif %}
            <p>
              <input type="text" name="username" autofocus maxlength="254" required
                id="id_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de usuario"/>
            </p>
            <p>
              <input type="password" name="password" required
                id="id_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
            </p>
            <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Acceder"></p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
{% endblock %}
```

Mi duda es si puedo añadirle estilos como en el ejemplo de arriba y estructurarlo en un `forms.py` y mostrarlo de la siguiente manera en el `template`: `{{ form.as_p }}`
Con todos los estilos, etc

Tengo otra duda y es sobre el ejemplo de arriba, ¿Una ves le de click al botón de acceder en el formulario, de la nada se envía los datos ingresados a `django`? no entiendo muy bien como funciona esta parte. ¿Como es que `django` recibe esos datos y hace la autenticasion?, les agradecería mucho que me lo explicaran..

***De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde mi punto de vista deberías de informarte un poco más sobre teoría básica de HTML y HTTP, así como un tutorial básico de Django. Dicho esto te explico.

Los estilos CSS van antes de que acabe la etiqueta `<head></head>` para optimizar el renderizado de la plantilla.

Si el formulario únicamente se va a mostrar en una única página puedes hacerlo en un formulario de Django, si lo quieres mostrar en varias páginas es más óptimo pintarlo en HTML tal y como haces, pues de lo contrario tendrías que crear un procesador de contexto. Para añadirle estilos te adjunto un ejemplo para el `forms.py`:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
username = forms.CharField(min_length=4, max_length=15,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Usuario'}))
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':u'Contraseña'}))
```

Cuando cliques en "Acceder" se enviará una petición de tipo POST a la URI indicada en el `action` del `form`, en este caso como no has indicado ninguna se enviaría a la URI en la cual estés, es decir, la que aparezca en la barra del navegador. Yo te recomiendo indicar en el `action` la URL, para ello:

```
{% url 'login' %}
```

Evidentemente tienes que registrar en `urls.py` el mapeo de la URI "login" con tu método del `views.py`.

Además, si quieres que tras iniciar sesión te redireccione a la página a la cual intentabas acceder pero para acceder requiere iniciar sesión, tendrás que insertar en el formulario el campo `next`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}"/>
```

Y por último, tienes que añadir el Token de seguridad CSRF para todos los formularios de tipo POST, si no te dará un error 403, pues éste, a no ser que lo desactives, es obligatorio para todas las peticiones de tipo POST. Por tanto, dentro del formulario tendrías que insertar:

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

Ejemplo de formulario en plantilla:

```
    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" class="form-horizontal form-control-line">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group m-t-40">
           <div class="col-xs-12">
              {{ login_form.username }}
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-xs-12">
              {{ login_form.password}}
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-center m-t-20">
           <div class="col-xs-12">
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block waves-effect" type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>
           </div>
        </div>
     </form>
```

Comment: Entonces los datos se envían por el método `post` a `django`, de que manera `django` recibe los datos por el método `post`? Los recibe en la vista?...

Comment: La petición es enviada a la URL indicada en el action del form, Django mediante el enrutador urls.py, tiene la conexión de dicha URL con un método del views.py, por lo que cuando envíes la petición HTTP de tipo POST a esa URL entrará por el método que le tengas asignado. Ahí será dónde trates el formulario.